# Rounding to the nearest integer in floating point

Tags: math, binary, integer, floating-point, rounding

How can I round a floating point number to the nearest integer? I am looking for the algorithm in terms of binary since I have to implement the code in assembly.

Comment: What hardware are you targetting? Most hardware will have dedicated ops for this. What data format are you using?

Comment: My hardware doesn't have floating point instructions.  I implemented floating point in software.  The architecture is a custom chip implemented by my group of which the details are not important.  So I am implementing IEEE-754 floating point and I need to convert to the nearest integer.  Preferably, the number will remain in floating point format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATED with method for proper rounding to even.

> **Basic Algorithm:**

Store the 23-exponent+1'th bit (after the decimal point). Next, zero out the (23-exponent) least significant bits.  Then use the stored bit and the new LSB to round.  If the stored bit bit is 1, add one to the LSB of the non-truncated part and normalize if necessary.  If the stored bit is 0, do nothing.

**

> **For results matching IEEE-754 standard:**

**
Before Zeroing out the (23-exponent) least significant bits, OR together the (22-exponent) least significant bits.  Call the result of that OR the rounding bit.
The stored (23-exponent + 1) bit (after the decimal point) will be called the guard bit.
Then zero out the (23-exponent) least significant bits).

If the guard bit is zero, do nothing.

If the guard bit is 1, and the sticky bit is 0, add one to the LSB if the LSB is 1.

If the guard bit is 1 and the sticky bit is 1, add one to the LSB.

---

Here are some examples using the basic algorithm:

x = 62.3

```
    sign exponent             mantissa
x =  0      5       (1).11110010011001100110011
```

Step 1: Store the exponent+1'th bit (after the decimal point)

exponent+1 = 6th bit

savedbit = 0

Step 2: Zero out 23-exponent least significant bits
23-exponent = 18, so we zero out the 18 LSBs

```
    sign exponent             mantissa
x =  0      5       (1).11110000000000000000000
```

Step 3: Use the next bit to round
Since the stored bit is 0, we do nothing, and the floating point number has been rounded to 62.

---

Another example:

x = 21.9

```
    sign exponent             mantissa
x =  0      4       (1).01011110011001100110011
```

Step 1: Store the exponent+1'th bit (after the decimal point)

exponent+1 = 5th bit

savedbit = 1

Step 2: Zero out 23-exponent least significant bits
23-exponent = 19, so we zero out the 19 LSBs

```
    sign exponent             mantissa
x =  0      4       (1).01010000000000000000000
```

Step 3: Use the next bit to round
Since the stored bit is 1, we add one to the LSB of the truncated part and get 22, which is the correct number:

We start with:

```
    sign exponent             mantissa
x =  0      4       (1).01010000000000000000000
```

Add one at this location:

```
+                          1
```

And we get 22:

```
    sign exponent             mantissa
x =  0      4       (1).01100000000000000000000
```

Comment: Almost; you need to handle exact halfway cases properly as well.

Comment: @StephenCanon, I believe my algorithm works for exact halfway cases as well.  For instance, 21.5 rounds to 22 using my algorithm.

Comment: @StephenCanon, It works for 20.5, 20.5 rounds to 21.  Exponent was 4, so we kept 4 most significant bits of mantissa, but the next bit was a 1, so we add one to the LSB of the truncated bits.  So a 1 gets added in the 4th position (from the left)

Comment: 20.5 should round to 20.  Remember, in IEEE-754 default rounding, exact halfway cases are broken towards the even result, not away from zero.

Comment: instead of looking only at the first fractional bits, you would look at all of the fractional bits; if the fractional bits are smaller than `.100...`, do nothing (as your code does now).  If they are greater than `.100...`, add one to the significand (as your code does now).  If they are equal to `.100...`, then add one to the significand only if the LSB of the significand is one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an SSE instruction for round to nearest: http://www.musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=246

```
inline int float2int(float x) {
    int i;
    __asm {
        fld x
        fistp i
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: How does one go about using it on AltiVec? NEON? VIS?

Comment: I can't use functions, i have to write in assembly (for a processor I work on).  The assembly language is not risc, nor x86, it is my groups' own language.  I just need to know how to manipulate the bits.  Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. I will leave my answer though for future reference.

Comment: Yes, hopefully someone it will help someone browsing, thanks anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Decrease the exponent by 1, add 1, increase the exponent by 1, truncate. Or just add 0.5 and truncate. Whichever floats your boat.

Comment: Umm..I don't see how that will work.  Example: x = 62.3, which should be rounded to 62.  The binary is 01000010011110010011001100110011.  So the exponent is 5.  By your method, exponent becomes 6, adding one makes mantissa 10.11110010011001100110011, then you said truncate.  So I get 2*2^6 = 128.

Comment: 2^5 becomes 2^4, Add one, mantissa becomes 10.11110010011001100110011, increase exponent, 2^5, then trucate, 2*2^5 = 64, still incorrect.

Comment: Okay, then switch them around.

Comment: I think you need to work out an example to prove yourself. It all computes as the incorrect answer when I worked it out.

Comment: 10.101 -> 101.01 -> 110.01 -> 11.001 -> 11.

Comment: That is a fixed point number.  Expand the number out to 32-bit floating point.

Comment: I can put 0s as far as the eye can see in both directions and it will still work, provided there's no overflow.

Comment: Okay, 62.3 has sign 0, exponent 5, mantissa (1).1110010011001100110011.  Shifting left one and adding 1 results in: 11. + 1 == 100, shifting right gives 10.  so then we are left with 2*2^5 = 64.  You aren't understanding floating point format.